# Directional derivative, linear transformation, and chain rule?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, probability-distributions, linear-transformations, chain-rule

Assume I have a probability density function $p(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and a transformation function $T:\mathbb{R}^d  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$

$$T(x)=x+\epsilon v(x)$$

where $\epsilon$ is a small scalar increment and $v(x)$ an evaluation of a smooth vector field $v$ at $x$. Assume further that I have $\nabla_x=[\frac{d}{d x_1},\frac{d}{d x_2},...,\frac{d}{d x_d}]^T$ and $\nabla_\epsilon=\frac{d}{d \epsilon}$.

I am trying to understand a derivation in which the following identity occurs:

$$\nabla_\epsilon p(T(x))=[\nabla_xp(T(x))]^T\cdot\nabla_\epsilon T(x)$$

How did the authors arrive here? The dimensions check out: $\nabla_\epsilon p(T(x))$ is a scalar, and the RHS is an inner product of two $d$-dimensional vectors which also yields a scalar. I assume the [chain rule of differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) was used here to obtain $\nabla_\epsilon T(x)$, but why do we obtain the first RHS vector? Where does the $\nabla_x$ come from?

I would appreciate any advice or help in understanding this.

Answer (score 1):

The identity can indeed by derived using the chain rule for the composition of a scalar field $f$ and a vector field $g$.  Using the $\nabla_x$ notation, this case of the chain rule is
$$
  (f\circ g)_i(x) = (\nabla_x f)(g(x)) \cdot g_i(x)
$$
The right side is the dot product of the vector $(\nabla_x f)(g(x))$ and the vector $g_i(x)$.  The subscript $i$ denotes the partial derivative with respect to variable $i$.

In your case, the scalar field is $p$ and the vector field is $T(x,\epsilon)$.  The way it is used in your identity, $T$ is really a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$.  The $\nabla_{\epsilon}$ operator is just the partial derivative with respect to variable $d+1$.  The left side of your identity is $(p\circ T)_{d+1}(x,\epsilon)$ and the chain rule applied to this is
$$
  (p\circ T)_{d+1}(x,\epsilon) = (\nabla_x p)(T(x,\epsilon)) \cdot (\nabla_{\epsilon}T)(x,\epsilon).
$$